# Error: unexpected '}' in: " }" Non-parametric vs. OLS in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm pretty new to R (used to use STATA), there seems to be an Error:unexpected '}' in: " }". I can't seem to find the issue. I am comparing nonparametric methods to pooled OLS to see which performs better in a public data set that was published a little while ago. I am aware that I have assigned a small loop and small n.train. Any help would be great. Much appreciated.

```
M <- 10
n.train <-90
n <- nrow(smokedatasample)

write(c("linear","ll"),file="psedata.xlsx",ncol=2)

train <- smokedatasample

sample.OLS <- lm(model.formula.birth,data=smokedatasample, x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
np.smoke.reg <- npreg(np.formula,data=smokedatasample,regtype="ll",nmulti=1)

pse.lm <- numeric()
pse.ll <- numeric()

for(m in 1:M) {

smoke.shuffle <- smokedatasample[sample(1:n,replace=FALSE),]

train <- smoke.shuffle[1:n.train,]
eval <- smoke.shuffle[(n.train+1):n,]

shuffle.sample.OLS <- lm(model.formula.birth, data=train)

yhat.OLS <- predict(shuffle.sample.OLS, newdata=eval)

pse.lm[m] <- mean((eval$dbirwt-yhat.OLS)^2)

shuffle.np.smoke.reg <- npreg(np.formula,data=train, regtype=np.smoke.reg$bws$regtype, 
                              ckertype=np.smoke.reg$bws$ckertype, 
                              ckerorder=np.smoke.reg$bws$ckerorder, 
                              ukertype=np.smoke.reg$bws$ukertype, 
                              okertype=np.smoke.reg$bws$okertype, 
                              bws=np.smoke.reg$bws$bw)

yhat.np <- predict(shuffle.np.smoke.reg, newdata=eval)

pse.ll[m] <- mean((eval$dbirwt-yhat.np)^2)

write(c(pse.lm[m],pse.ll[m], file= "psedata.xlsx" , ncol=2 ,append=TRUE)

}
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in the last command. It should be `c(pse.lm[m],pse.ll[m])`

Comment: I suggest using an IDE that will aid you in finding matching parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a bracket in the last line before `}`.

```
write(c(pse.lm[m],pse.ll[m]), file= "psedata.xlsx" , ncol=2 ,append=TRUE)
```

instead of

```
write(c(pse.lm[m],pse.ll[m], file= "psedata.xlsx" , ncol=2 ,append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it must have been late ;)